# Returning the last insert row of same id group in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using create payment receipt i will pay some amount like below example

this already created receipt but again have pay due_amount

```
cust_id   cust_name  invoice_id  paid_amount  due amount  makeapayment

1001       SAS              545      76           305          sasi
```

This is the result of my query.
I have to pay due amount 100 then create another row after paying in same "id"  view new row old row  not view only stay in database   see  result like this

```
cust_id   cust_name  invoice_id  paid_amount  due amount  makeapayment

1001       SAS              545       76           205          sasi
```

present i am using query

```
SELECT pid, cust_id, cust_name, date, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, paid_amount, paymentmade, makeapayment, due_amount, status FROM print_reciept
group by cust_id having due_amount!='0' ORDER BY pid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
SELECT pid, cust_id, cust_name, date, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, paid_amount, paymentmade, makeapayment, due_amount, status 
FROM print_reciept AS pr
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(pid) AS last_pid, cust_id
    FROM print_reciept
    GROUP BY cust_id
) AS tmp ON (tmp.cust_id = pr.cust_id AND tmp.last_pid > pr.pid)
GROUP BY cust_id 
ORDER BY pid DESC
```

Comment: does not retrieve any value is totally empty sir give me another query